# Mongo "error converting js type to Utf8Value" on db.currentOp()?

Tags: mongodb, character-encoding

Database is running slow... is a 11gb database of around ~4 million documents.

db.currentOp() produces:

```
Thu Jun 26 21:32:10.979 Assertion: 16686:error converting js type to Utf8Value
0x10e703360 0x10e6dcc2a 0x10e6da0dd 0x10e6c1aa8 0x10e6bd207 0x10e8fd0d9 0x10e900381 0x10e971b18 0x1469a3906362 0x1469a391701e
 0   mongo                               0x000000010e703360 _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 64
 1   mongo                               0x000000010e6dcc2a _ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc + 186
 2   mongo                               0x000000010e6da0dd _ZN5mongo11toSTLStringERKN2v86HandleINS0_5ValueEEE + 109
 3   mongo                               0x000000010e6c1aa8 _ZN5mongo7V8Scope16mongoToV8ElementERKNS_11BSONElementEb + 4792
 4   mongo                               0x000000010e6bd207 _ZN5mongoL8namedGetEN2v85LocalINS0_6StringEEERKNS0_12AccessorInfoE + 839
 5   mongo                               0x000000010e8fd0d9 _ZN2v88internal8JSObject35GetPropertyAttributeWithInterceptorEPS1_PNS0_6StringEb + 665
 6   mongo                               0x000000010e900381 _ZN2v88internal10JSReceiver32GetPropertyAttributeWithReceiverEPS1_PNS0_6StringE + 289
 7   mongo                               0x000000010e971b18 _ZN2v88internal19Runtime_HasPropertyENS0_9ArgumentsEPNS0_7IsolateE + 104
 8   ???                                 0x00001469a3906362 0x0 + 22443948270434
 9   ???                                 0x00001469a391701e 0x0 + 22443948339230
```

mongostat --all produces:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res non-mapped faults              locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  18.6g  40.2g  1.71g      21.6g   3213 directoryListings:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     4k    71   21:34:08
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  18.6g  40.2g   1.7g      21.6g   3166 directoryListings:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     4k    71   21:34:09
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  18.6g  40.2g   1.7g      21.6g   2908 directoryListings:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     4k    71   21:34:10
```

Completely lost. Why would currentOp() return that error? If it had to do with character encoding as the error suggests why would Mongo let me put things in the DB that are the "wrong" character encoding? o_o

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I'm getting the same error retrieving from system.profile.find().sort({"ts":-1}).limit(100).pretty() ... never when pretty() is omitted.  I am running version 3.0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in MongoDB if you're using one of the versions mentioned here

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17101
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12600